# React native is hanging while running create-react-native-app <Project_name>

Tags: node.js, react-native

I'm using:

- Nodejs 6
- Windows 7

When trying to install `create-react-native-app` I get the following error:

> Using package manager as npm with npm interface.
>
> Installing packages. This might take a couple minutes.
>
> Installing react-native-scripts...
>
> npm WARN deprecated socks@1.1.10: If using 2.x branch, please upgrade to at least 2.1.6 to avoid a serious bug with socket data flow and an import issue introduced in 2.1.0
>
> [......] | extract:@expo/ngrok-bin-linux-arm64: sill pacote @expo/n

Comment: wait, it'll take some time.

Comment: Waiting for response too.

Comment: I waited for long time - almost half a day and then gave up. Its not working though. Any other alternative Solution pls?